# How to use import statement in jenkisfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am running a groovy script which needs access to two modules
jeninks.model and hudson.model

i tried importing these two via import statement in my jenkinsfile but the issue is still there.

Error:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: build for class: groovy.lang.Binding
at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)

Any solution by which i can do this?

The script is working fine when i am using a freestyle job with Execute System Groovy.

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*

pipeline{
    agent any 
    stages{
        stage('py version'){
            steps{
                bat 'python --version'
            }
        }
        stage('get jobs'){
            get_job()
        }
    }
}


def get_job(){

    def cutOfDate = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2

    def filename = build.workspace.toString() + "/jobs_lists.txt"
    targetFile = new File(filename).write("")
    targetFile = new File(filename).append("<table><tr><th>Job Name</th><th>Last Build on</th><th>Keep</th><th>username</th></tr>")
    println "Cut of Date: " + cutOfDate

}
```

Comment: Please share the contents of your Jenkins file.

Comment: import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*

pipeline{
    agent any 
    stages{
        stage('py version'){
            steps{
                bat 'python --version'
            }
        }
        stage('get jobs'){
            get_job()
        }
    }
}
def get_job(){
    def cutOfDate = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2
    def filename = build.workspace.toString() + "/jobs_lists.txt"  // giving erre
    println "Cut of Date: " + cutOfDate
}

Comment: Please use this link to see: https://codeshare.io/wn87k7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to access the Workspace DIR you can use the $WORKSPACE environment variable.

Example :

```
def get_job(){

    def cutOfDate = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2
    println("$WORKSPACE")
    def filename = "$WORKSPACE" + "/jobs_lists.txt"
    targetFile = new File(filename).write("")
    targetFile = new File(filename).append("<table><tr><th>Job Name</th><th>Last Build on</th><th>Keep</th><th>username</th></tr>")
    println "Cut of Date: " + cutOfDate

}
```

If you want to access the current build context use `currentBuild` which will return a [RunWrapper](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html).  Example below.

```
def changeset = currentBuild.changeSets
```

**Update : Accessing Jobs from the Pipeline**

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script{
                    getJobs()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


def getJobs() {
    Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each { jobitem ->
          def jobName = jobitem.name
          def jobInfo = Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName)
          println(jobName)
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to access Jenkins jobs for which i need those dependencies like:

`for (job in Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class)) { build = job.getLastBuild() }`

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @unknown You don't have to import anything to access Jenkins Jobs. Please refer the updated answer. This should work. If you get permission issues just make sure you approve the script execution from https://<JENKINS_URL>/scriptApproval/